# video is not showing in fullscreen in ios device in youtube_player_flutter package

Tags: flutter, youtube-player-flutter

I'm using youtube_player_flutter package for playing youtube video.
It's working in android but in IOS device while tapping on fullscreen button, video is not showing in full-screen. please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `youtube_player_flutter` to `youtube_player_iframe package` and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).